# CAKeyframeAnimation path to Define Opacity?

Tags: ios, cakeyframeanimation

Can CAKeyframeAnimation be used with a path instead of keyframe values
to animate (non-position) properties? Here is the key code:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *theLeftGradientAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
theLeftGradientAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
theLeftGradientAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
theLeftGradientAnimation.duration = (isToClose ? self.fromDuration : self.toDuration);

//test with a linear monotonic path to define the opacity function response
UIBezierPath    *shadePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[shadePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0)];  //ASSUME coords are: x->t y->alpha(t)
[shadePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(1.0f, 1.0f)];  //ASSUME time normalized to duration
[shadePath closePath];

theLeftGradientAnimation.path = shadePath.CGPath;
```

However, this does **not** quite work properly- the opacity does animate smoothly, though not monotonically or exactly according to changes in the path (assumes that the path is 'normalized' from (0.0,0.0) to (1.0,1.0) like an easing function). Note that I'm **not** animating the position or moving a layer on a path, but would hope to use it for any animatable property.

There is some ambiguity in the documentation that suggests that a path can be used thus to effectively to define the transfer function of animation time vs. property being animated (thus substitutes for an array of keyframe values that would be created based on that transfer function). Also in the iOS 6 documentation for "Keyframe Timing and Pacing Extensions" does attempt to clarify use of path vs. values, but is still ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `CAKeyframeAnimation` has a `timingFunctions` (plural) property, and ignores the `timingFunction`. In your case, since you want monotony, you will probably want to set `theLeftGradientAnimation.timingFunction = kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear`. The default timingFunction does indeed interpolate non-linearly.

See the docs for a more in-depth description of timingFunctions, and how to provide your own `CAMediaTimingFunction` if the built-in ones do not suffice.

Comment: Use of timingFunction would be redundant if specifying the path property worked as assumed (tried with no luck too). Note that test code specifies a linear-monotonic function only for purposes of determining how this might work. Ultimately, I want to use a complex non-linear function to animate properties in this way (no way to customize with functionWithControlPoints::::).

Comment: My apologies for not being clear on this intent.

Use of timingFunctions (plural) also would be redundant as its optional use is pertinent when specifying keyframe values rather than a path as well. Unfortunately there is a dearth of CAKeyframeAnimation code samples around, let alone any to know if this usage is valid.

Comment: Reading the documentation, it seems to me that the path does not contain a timing component at all, instead just acting effectively as a list of evenly spaced values. How a CGPoint value would translate to a scalar value such as alpha, I don't know. If I were you, I'd first try with just `values` and `keyTimes`, experimenting which `calculationMode` works best. Re-reading the documentation for `timingFunctions`, `timingFunction` (singular) doesn't work at all with `CAKeyframeAnimation`. How are you observing your values?

Comment: The assumption (guess really) is that the path x coord maps to t and y coord to x(t) (property to be animated e.g. alpha)- this would then behave exactly like the kCAMediaTimingFunction curves.

Comment: I'm testing only on the simulator (probably a bad idea)- but I can modify the two points of the path in the code above and it varies the alpha animation (just not in a way the makes total sense).

You may be right and I may just have to generate the arrays for the keyframe values instead- but the continuous path approach did seem worth a shot.